# Java Name Guessing Game - How To Access Arrays Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, syntax

```
public class NameGuessingGame {
    public static void main(String [] Args) {

        String[] BarackObama= {
            "He's A Famous American", 
            "He Lives in the whitehouse", 
            "He has two kids", 
            "He's name means one is blessed", 
            "He's Fifty Six Years Old",
        };

        String[] AmirKhan= {
            "He's a famous boxer", 
            "He Lives in Bolton", 
            "He's Currently in im a celeb", 
            "He has two daughters", 
            "He won a silver award in Two Thousand and Four",
        };

        String[] Tomcruise= {
            "He's age is Fifty Five", 
            "Started A film Career", 
            "He's the highest paid actor Hollywood", 
            "His first film was endless love", 
            "Has one three golden globe awards" 
        };

        String[] ImranKhan= {
            "He's age is Sixty Five", 
            "Khan retired from cricket in ninety ninety Two", 
            "In Ninety Ninety six he joined policitics", 
            "Started playing cricket at the age of 13", 
            "His Networth is fifety million"
        };

        String[] CristianoRonaldo= {
            "He's age is thirty two", 
            "He has four children", 
            "He joined football at the age of sixteen", 
            "Signed a five-year thirty one million contract", 
            " He was born in portugal"
        };
    }
}

Public Static Void GuessMethod(String[] Guess)
```

Question Here Is Guys Would Be How Could I Access The Data From The Arrays in this `GuessMethid`. Using A Index Such As One Statement At A Time? Would I have Something Such As `String[]BarackObama [0] = J.Option.Dialogbox` To Read A Input From User As I will Allow Users To Guess The Right Answer From Statements. Any Help Would Be Perfect Thank You

EDIT ---
Hi guys so what Im trying to do, Is use the statements in the arrays in a dialog box one by one and then read in a Input from the user, for example answer will be Barack Obama and then the dialog will tell me if the answer is correct or not I know how to use j option pane and dialog boxes. It's just the matter of how do I implement these arrays in this guess who method. I have used arrays before and also methods but don't quote understand how to use arrays in a method thanks...

Comment: Question definitely needs rephrasing. It is not clear what are you searching for, what you tried and what are the expected results

Comment: The data needs to be re-structured. Also it is still a little unclear where your problem is: I know you want to make a guessing game but I am not sure what your exact problem is. Also, there's a major algorithmic problem you need to solve by yourself and probably needs some rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

use a loop

```
for(String question : BarackObama){
  // question will be "He's A Famous American" in first iteration,
  //"He Lives in the whitehouse" in second iteration ans so on.
  //you can get display question and get input from the user here

 }
```